# Access File in bin folder of Java web application

Tags: java, web, classpath, src

I want to read a text file from src folder of class activitydata. In order to do that, I wrote following code

```
ActivityData c = new ActivityData();
         Class<? extends ActivityData> cls = c.getClass();
         URL url = cls.getResource("file.txt");
         System.out.println("Value = " + url);
```

Although I get the url in console, when I write following code I get exception:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(url.toString()));
```

Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\G:\Study%20Folder.......\file.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Comment: It is a Java dynamic web application in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

In Java web applications, you can't assume you'll have access to your resources as `File`s. Use `getResourceAsStream` instead.

Comment: Hi I managed to answer this question by following InputStream filestream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MainDataScript.js");

        Gson gson = new Gson(); 

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(filestream) );

Comment: But I want to know, what if I want to write  the same file ?

Comment: @ArkoMahmud You don't. You aren't guaranteed to be able to write inside a webapp.